# Linq syntax in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

What I really want is to select these two tables in to an anon type like in Scott Gu's blog: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx?CommentPosted=true) However, I would settle for this created type "ActiveLots" I am joining two tables together and want to be able to reference columns from each in my result set.

I don't seem to be getting the syntax correctly.

```
 Dim pi = From p In dc.Inventories Join i In dc.InventoryItems On p.InventoryItemID _
                     Equals i.InventoryItemID Where p.LotNumber <> "" _
                     Select New ActiveLots LotNumber = p.LotNumber, Quantity = p.Quantity, Item = i.Item, Uom = i.UnitofMeasure, Description = i.Description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Daniel Moth's blog entry](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/02/anonymous-types-in-c-30-and-vb9.html). I suspect you want:

```
Dim pi = From p In dc.Inventories _
         Join i In dc.InventoryItems
              On p.InventoryItemID Equals i.InventoryItemID _
         Where p.LotNumber <> "" _
         Select New With { .LotNumber = p.LotNumber, .Quantity = p.Quantity, _
                           .Item = i.Item, .Uom = i.UnitofMeasure, _
                           .Description = i.Description }
```

That's using an anonymous type - to use a concrete type, you'd use `New ActiveLots With { ...` (where `ActiveLots` has to have a parameterless constructor).

Comment: Jon, your assumption about "New ActiveLot With..." is correct. Obviously ActiveLot needs an empty constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Meta-Knight. Will edit appropriately.